# Is there a list of public repos using smartpy?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

I'd like to see more complex examples of smartpy being used in main net contracts.

So far, I've found [tzcolor's auction house contract](https://github.com/tzcolors/tzcolors-contract/blob/main/auction_house.py) SUPER helpful. Are there any other really good examples (that are deployed on the main net) to learn from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among others, some major contracts:

- [Hic Et Nunc](https://www.hicetnunc.xyz/)

[primary contract on main net](https://github.com/hicetnunc2000/hicetnuncDAO)

deprecated (merged into primary contract): [objkt-swap contract](https://github.com/hicetnunc2000/objkt-swap)

deprecated (merged into primary contract): [hicetnuncNFT](https://github.com/hicetnunc2000/hicetnuncNFTs)

- Kolibri

https://github.com/Hover-Labs/LP-Token-Contracts

https://github.com/Hover-Labs/liquidation-pool

- Harbinger

https://github.com/tacoinfra/harbinger-contracts

- Airgap team

https://github.com/tzbutton/tzbutton-contract

https://github.com/tzcolors/tzcolors-contract

- Oropocket (XTZGold & XTZSilver smart contracts)

https://github.com/vinnyson/oropocket_smartcontracts

- and, of course, SmartPy templates

https://gitlab.com/SmartPy/smartpy/-/tree/master/python/templates